# Can you please help me get the following python code corrected?

Tags: python

Am very new to learning python and is trying to instantiate an object of the first class I have just wrote.

My python class code reads as follows:

```
class Staff:
    def _init_(self, pPosition, pName, pPay):
        self.position = pPosition
        self.name = pName
        self.pay = pPay
        print("Creating Staff object.")

    def _str_(self):

        return "Position = %s, Name = %s, Pay = %d" %(self.position, self.name, self.pay)

    def calculatePay(self):

        prompt = "Enter number of hours worked for %s" %(self.name)

        hours = input(prompt)

        promt = "Enter the hourly rate for %s" %(self.name)

        hourlyRate = input(prompt)

        self.pay = int(hours)*int(hourlyRate)

        return self.pay
```

Now I am trying to instantiate it by running the file from "Run Module" tab in the text editor of the IDLE Python shell with the following code:

```
officeStaff1 = Staff('Basic', 'Yvonne', 0)
```

But, getting the following error on pressing enter after it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    officeStaff1 = Staff('Basic', 'Yvonne', 0)
TypeError: Staff() takes no arguments
```

Can you explain to me what wrong am I doing here and what correction is needed to make the code workable?

Best Regards,
Dibyarka

Comment: It should be `__init__`, Not `_init_`

Comment: Dupe : you have no `__init__(self, pPosition, pName, pPay):` method - you only have a `_init_(self, pPosition, pName, pPay):`

Comment: Similarly, should be `__str__`

Comment: Thanks bro, that worked. Thanks for the trouble you took to help me.